# window.returnValue returning undefined for IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm writing a intranet system and i have to use IE 7.

In IE7 there is a method called "window.showmodaldialog" that is supposed to return the value passed in the modal as in: window.returnValue = "some string".

My code is 
index.jsp

```
var result = window.showmodaldialog(url)
```

modal.jsp:

```
window.returnValue = "some string"
```

But the "result" var is always undefined when i close the modal. The domain and protocol are the same. And window.opener is undefined.

In modal.jsp the legacy system make some refresh and redirects and we have to keep that way. Is this the problem? If is, is there a way to fix? I really need to keep using window.returnValue, because the system can open others model that i don't have the source.

EDIT:
Adding more info about modal.jsp:

```
 var jsonReturn = {"one_tag": "some value", "id": "id"};
 jsonReturn = JSON.stringify(jsonReturn);
 window.returnValue = jsonReturn;
 window.close();
```

Some select box submit a form to modal.jsp, making the page to refresh.

Comment: Sounds weird, dialogs have always been "the best part of IE" and they've worked as expected so far. Can you elaborate what "refresh and redirects" are, and the stage they occur? Can you provide more code, especially what happens immediately after `showModalDialog()` in main page and the code after assigning a value to the `returnValue` in dialog?

Comment: The refresh and redirects are form submits to the same url. I really think that somehow it is return the window.returnValue for another window, but I can't figure how.

Comment: There is no support for `JSON` in IE7, it's available IE>=8. Strange if there wasn't any errors in modal dialog...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, i'm using a lib to allow JSON in IE7.

Comment: Interesting, is the lib loaded to the modal dialog too? If you put `alert(returnValue)` before `window.close()`, what does it say?

Comment: Yes, is in the modal too. alert(window.returnValue) shows me {"one_tag": "some value", "id": "id"}

Comment: Well, i found the error, someone put a function with the name "returnValue", since everything in js is in window. the function overwrote the default IE variable.